# Send user created li to php as array without removed li elements?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, html-lists

I have looked everywhere for a week and I cannot get this to work.

I have an ul and the user adds and removes items from a list until he/she is satisfied with the result and clicks next. This is part of a larger form. I need to send all the li elements to a php page as an array.

I've used jquery and hidden inputs and the list works fine and it sends the data as an array to php, element by element when clicking 'Add'. **The problem is, when the user removes an item from the list, it obviously only gets removed from the front-end.**

**So I think I need to let the user create and edit the list first and then when clicking 'submit', get all the remaining li into an array and send it to php via ajax.(?)** Or find a way to remove the same element from the php array (which sounds inefficient). Either way I need to send data to php some other way like ajax and I can't get this to work.

*As you can probably tell, I'm a beginner but I would really really apreciate it if someone could show me a basic but complete example as I have already tried everything I could find and I must be assuming something false. Thank you!*

Comment: it would be easier if you attached your current codes

Comment: can u add the code u have currently

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<ul id="xyz">
    <li>Your Items</li>
<ul>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#next").click(function (){
   var arr = [];
   $("#abc").find("li").each(function(){
      arr.push($(this).html());
   });
   $.post("link-to-php", {array: arr}, function(result){
      //
   });
});
```

**PHP**

you can access the array with `$_POST["array"]`. You should check if the array is valid and then you can update your php array.

For better usage you can json encode the array in jQuery (`JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr))`) and decode it in php(`json_decode($_POST["array"], true);`).